# Why do I get the following error "[Open3D ERROR] GLFW Error: The GLFW library is not initialized"?

Tags: networking, server

I'm trying to visualize some point cloud on my server and display it on my laptop, but I got the following error:

```
[Open3D ERROR] GLFW Error: X11: Failed to open display 10.109.4.97:0.0
[Open3D ERROR] Failed to initialize GLFW
[Open3D ERROR] GLFW Error: The GLFW library is not initialized
```

I've created a docker environment on the server with the following code:

```
nvidia-docker run -it --name S1 --privileged -p 10139:22 --shm-size=15G -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix\$DISPLAY -e GDK_SCALE -e GDK_DPI_SCALE -v /home/data/:/data -d  ffbf123c17cc /bin/bash
```

my bashrc file contents are as follows:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

shopt -s histappend

HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
#fi
export DISPLAY=10.109.4.97:0.0
#export DISPLAY=172.17.0.1:0
alias pycharm="${PYCHARM_HOM}/data/pycharm-community-2021.2.1/bin/pycharm.sh"
#export PYTHONPATH=/data/gitlab/fusion_WLR732_L
export PYTHONPATH=/data/gitlab/shanghaifusion
export PATH=/data/spcmake/cmake-3.19.4/bin:/opt/conda/bin/numba:/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/sitepackages/numba:$PATH
#export DISPLAY=10.100.75.197:0.0  #ubuntu或笔记本电脑ip
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:${PATH}
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
#alias pycharm="${PYCHARM_HOM}/data/pycharm-community-2021.2.1/bin/pycharm.sh"
#export PYTHONPATH=/data/spconv/spconv/:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/TensorRT-7.2.1.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/TensorRT-7.2.1.6/targets/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export TR_PATH=/data/TensorRT-7.2.1.6
export PATH=$PATH:$TR_PATH/bin
sh: 1: q: not found
/usr/local/opencv4.5/lib
/usr/local/opencv4.5/lib
/usr/local/opencv4.5/lib
/usr/local/opencv4.5/lib
```

I've enabled X11 forwarding on the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

I've installed VcXsrv on my laptop with windows 10 and configured it,
I connect the container on the server with visual studio code on windows 10 .

I made sure every configuration is correct.
I can display on other laptops, but not mine(10.109.4.97).